# Depreciation problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, percentages

I take 900ml of a liquid and dilute it with 100ml of water. Then I take 900ml of the mixture and dilute it with 100ml of water. I repeat this process twenty times.

What proportion of the original liquid remains in the mixture at the end?

How much mixture should I take if I want it to contain 20ml of the original liquid?

Sorry I didn't know what to tag this question as and I forgot to write in a part of the problem.

Comment: What does this have to do with depreciation or finance?

Comment: @XanderHenderson the problem was from a chapter on depreciation and financial maths, so I would think that the working out has something to do with it, therefore I tagged it under finance.

Comment: Note that the two answers read the problem quite differently, based on different interpretations of what you are repeating.  Please clarify.

Comment: I forgot to put in a part of the question @RossMillikan. Sorry about that.

Comment: Then you should edit the question-there is a button below it-to add the information in.

Answer (score 1):

> I take 900ml of a liquid and dilute it with 100ml of water.

Let $a_n$ be the original liquid left in the mix after $n$ steps, with $a_1=900\,$.

> I repeat this process twenty times.

On the assumption that "*repeat this process*" literally means "*take 900ml of a liquid and dilute it with 100ml of water*": $\;a_{n+1} = 0.9 \,a_n\,$, since at each step $100 \,\text{ml}$ of the previous mix are discarded to make room for the new $100 \,\text{ml}$ of water, and what's discarded includes $\,\frac{100}{1000}=0.1\,$ of the original liquid that still existed in the previous mix. Therefore $a_n=0.9^{n-1} a_1\,$, and for $n= 20 \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You started with $900$ ml and added $2000$ ml of water.  The fact that you did it in steps does not matter at all.  What proportion is the original solution now?

Comment: `The fact that you did it in steps does not matter at all` Depends on how you read "*repeat this process twenty times*", I guess. In my reading, what gets "*re-processed*" is only $1000$ ml at each step.